# Windows Identiy foundation redistributable failed on Vista Home Premium edition

Tags: wif, geneva-framework

Yesterday it was announed that WIF - Windows Identity Foundation SDK RC was released in public domain. I tried installing the msu file from MSDN on my PC which has Home Premium edition of Vista and it failed? Microsoft mentions that Vista is supported but does not mention any versions of Vista on the site...Does anyone have similar problems??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same issue on a Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition box. I had the WIF Beta 2 uninstalled prior to installing the RC. Any chance that the .msu is confused with something that is left behind by the B2 uninstall script.

Frank

Update...

Found a thread on MS Geneva forum that talks about needing SP2 for WS 2008 and Vista. Just finished installing the RC.

Download link - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a4dd31d5-f907-4406-9012-a5c3199ea2b3&displaylang=en

Good luck.

Comment: Installed Vista Service Pack 2 and installed it..Why does the product literacture not say it...It says now when they have released the RTM version of WIF...

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem on Windows 2008 Server. MSU files failed saying "The update does not apply to your computer". Also prior to installing Windows Identity Foundation SDK installation asked for "Windows Identity Foundation Runtime". From where I can get "Windows Identity Foundation Runtime"?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the WIF runtime for Vista/W2K8(win6) and Win7/W2K8R2(win6.1) (for x86 and x64 systems), as well as the SDK, from the [MSDN Evaluation Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dd440951.aspx).

If you want the SDK, you have to install the runtime before the SDK.

Christian

Comment: the 6.0 msu fails to install on my Vista Home premium edition

Comment: When you run "wusa.exe Windows6.0-KB974405-x86.msu /log", that should give you some log information. What is the error message?